# HotSwap Wicket HTML Files does not work in Intellij maven + tomcat

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, wicket, hotswap

My HotSwap run configuration just works for java and not for html.

I am running a Wicket application on Tomcat, which I start with mvn tomcat7:run.

In my runner Configuration (Runner Tab VM Options) I entered:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=61515
```

Here is the run configuration:

[image]

Also I created a Remote Starter

[image]

Now I start (not debug) Tomcat Local H2 and after that I start as debug the Tomcat Hotswap Run configuration.

When I change a java class it works after  CTRL+SHIFT+F9, but when I change some html files it will not be rebuild.

Does anyone have a suggestion what I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Wicket in Development mode to update the HTML, otherwise Wicket caches the loaded markup on the first load and never checks again the file system.

If you are already running in DEV mode then make sure the updated HTML files end up in the classpath of your application, i.e. IDEA should copy them from your sources folder to the `WEB-INF/classes/**` folder when you make your module/project. Wicket will reload them from there if the modification time of an HTML is newer than the last time it was loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am running in DEV mode. The files (compiled Java classes as well) are within projectName\target\classe. If I open html within that path and update it works, but if I edit original and save or STRG+SHIFT+F9, it will not update the file within target.

Comment: `\target\classes` folder tells me that you use Maven as a build tool. Are the HTML files in `src\main\resources\` folder ? If they are in `src\main\java\` then you need to add `build\resources` section in your build to `include`  *.html. Then in IDEA do Build > Build Module. This will copy them to the target folder.

Comment: Hey Martin, my html files are within `\src\main\webapps\pages` . I figured out, that If I am within Project View and right click on the folder of contained html file and Rebuild, it will refresh. Your solution will build (I think) all files. Both work. What I was looking for was, that If I save the html file or click CTRL+SHIFT+F9 only the HTML-File is rebuild and updated.

Comment: Do you have a configured `IResourceFinder` (like `WebApplicationPath`) for this folder in `YourApplication#init()` method ? I guess you do, otherwise it won't work at all. But if you have it then it should be used by Wicket to see that the markup files have changed.